# get pixel of image in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, pixel, convolution

I am new by tensorflow. I want to write a Neural network, that gets noisy images from a file and uncorrupted images from another file.
then I want to correct noisy images based on the other images.

Answer (score 1):

What you are talking about is a [denoising autoencoder](https://gist.github.com/blackecho/3a6e4d512d3aa8aa6cf9).

This is not my code.  It was ranked very high on google search, has several github stars and forkes, all which are great indicators that it is a working and supported implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I'm trying to train a NN that get corrupted images and based on them the grand truth, remove noise from that images.It must be Network in Network, an another word pixels independent.